# How do I use pytesseract with python (spyder)?

Tags: python, ocr, spyder, python-tesseract

I have downloaded pytesseract from [here](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/), (tesseract-ocr-setup-3.05.00dev-205-ge205c59.exe) it was executed and saved on Program Files (x86).

Then I tried to run the following code on Spyder, but I got error *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract'*. I am not sure what else should I do to use pytesseract?

```
import cv2 
import pytesseract

IMG_DIR = 'Pictures/'
image = cv2.imread(IMG_DIR + 'aurebesh.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You downloaded only `tesseract` (C/C++ program), not `pytesseract` (Python module).

`pytesseract` is Python module which uses `tesseract` to work.

`pytesseract` is so called `wrapper` on `tesseract`.

You have to run in console:

```
pip install pytesseract
```

to install Python module.

---

At this moment you can only run `tesseract.exe` (C/C++ program) in console/terminal - ie.

```
tesseract.exe --help

tesseract.exe image.jpg output
```

Or you can run it in Python with

```
subprocess.run("tesseract.exe --help", shell=True)

subprocess.run("tesseract.exe image.jpg output", shell=True)
```

but they may need to use `/full/path/to/tesseract.exe` and `/full/path/to/image.jpg`

---

**BTW:**

`pytesseract` also uses `subprocess.run("/full/path/to/tesseract.exe ...")` to execute code but it has functions which make it all much simpler.

Comment: Thank you! Where exactly do I download pytesseract?

Comment: I ran "pip install pytesseract" in my python console in Spyder, and it seems to have worked well.